# Using create migration primitive with truffle

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, migration

I am following [this guide](https://blog.abuiles.com/blog/2017/07/08/writing-smart-contracts-with-truffle/) doing custom migrations with truffle.

When I run `truffle create migration deploy_hello_world` it creates this path `migrations/1501429988_deploy_hello_world.js/migration.js`. Once I configure the deployer and rename the `migration.js` file and remove the parent folder I run `truffle migrate --reset` and receive this error:

```
truffle migrate --reset
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:36916
  throw new Error("Could not find artifacts for " + import_path + " from any sources");
  ^

Error: Could not find artifacts for ./Migrations.sol from any sources
    at Resolver.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:36916:9)
    at ResolverIntercept.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:219315:32)
    at /Users/mokn1/Development/Ethereum/hello-world/migrations/1_initial_migration.js:1:28
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:32:29)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInNewContext (vm.js:38:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:83185:14
    at tryToString (fs.js:449:3)
```

Not sure what I need to do to get past this step as it seems to be an issue with running the primitive itself. Thank you for any help.